# Trying to give the field's ID to the JQuery instead of its Name

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

I was trying to pass the Input fields by its ID instead of the Name. If I put the input field's Name below, it works.

```
$('#textName_insert'):
```

but after putting the ID, Id does not work any more.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            $('#textName_insert'): {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            $('#textadr1_insert'): {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        }
    });

  });


<form id="insertForm" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="InsertAgentSrvlt">
          <fieldset id="modal_form">                  
            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Name:</label>
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <input id="textName_insert" name="textName" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md"/>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Key is the name of an element in jQuery validatior plugin. You have to give the name ,not ID.

Read [this](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)